# Deriving the formula for transforming random variables

Tags: calculus, probability, random-variables

I try to obtain the formula of transforming the probability density function of a random variable $X$, into the probability density function of another variable $Y$, which are related with a one-to-one function $g$ as $Y=g(X)$; the formula which involves the Jacobian factor. I am trying to derive in the following way: In a small interval $(y,y+\delta y)$, the probability of $Y$ is given as $\int_y^{y+\delta y}p_y(y)dy$ where $p_y(y)$ is the pdf for $Y$. Now, since $g$ is a one-to-one function, $g^{-1}$ maps $Y$ to an interval $(g^{-1}(y),g^{-1}(y+\delta y))$ in $X$'s domain. So it should be:

$$ \int_y^{y+\delta y}p_y(y)dy = \int_{g^{-1}(y)}^{g^{-1}(y+\delta y)}p_x(x)dx = \int_{g^{-1}(y)}^{g^{-1}(y+\delta y)}p_x(g^{-1}(y))dx$$

Then I divide both sides to $\delta y$ and take limit as $\delta y \to 0$:

$$ \lim_{\delta y \to 0}\dfrac{\int_y^{y+\delta y}p_y(y)dy}{\delta y}=\lim_{\delta y \to 0}\dfrac{\int_{g^{-1}(y)}^{g^{-1}(y+\delta y)}p_x(g^{-1}(y))dx}{\delta y}$$.

From the fundamental theorem of calculus the left limit gives $p_y(y)$ but I don't know how to apply the limit in the right side of the equation. How to proceed here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach:

Assume that the inverse of $g$ is an increasing and differentiable function, then

$$F_{g(X)}(x)=P(g(X)<x)=P(X<g^{-1}(x))=F_X(g^{-1}(x)).$$
If the inverse is drecreasing (and is differentiable)  then
$$F_{g(X)}(x)=P(g(X)<x)=P(X> g^{-1}(x))=1-F_X(g^{-1}(x)).$$

From here, one can calculate the density function by deriving $F_X(g^{-1}(x))$ with respect to  $x$.

That is,

$$f_{g(X)}(x)=f_X(g^{-1}(x))\begin{vmatrix}\frac{dg^{-1}(x)}{dx}\end{vmatrix}.$$